# Broadcom wireless monitor mode freezes system

Tags: wifi, broadcom, airmon-ng

I have a `broadcom BCM43142` wireless card, and wish to enable monitor mode. I'm using the `broadcom-sta` `wl` driver, manually upgraded to the latest version. This card is not supported by the `b43` driver.

Monitor mode is not supported on the `wlan0` interface, but according to the documentation, this should enable a `prism0` interface with monitoring capabilities:

```
echo 1 > /proc/brcm_monitor0
```

The moment I write `1` to that file, however, my system freezes completely.

How can I enable monitor mode, switch to another driver, or at least debug the freezing problem?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, this is due to a bug in the driver.
The new Broadcom source has already patched this so there's no need to manually patch it.

**For A X64 System try**

```
mkdir broadcom

cd broadcom

wget http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271.tar.gz

tar xzf http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271.tar.gz

build
```

**For A x32 System try**

```
mkdir broadcom

cd broadcom

wget http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271.tar.gz

tar xzf http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271.tar.gz

build
```

Then follow the instructions from the [STA readme to install it](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README_6.30.223.271.txt)

Comment: Can you link where to obtain the latest drivers? I went to the obvious place in broadcom.com and the downloads section didn't list my network card

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the driver. You have to patch the driver and compile it yourself.
See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/387780/cant-change-brcm-monitor0-in-proc